# Postfix server didn't send emails to the final destination

Tags: postfix, redhat, smtp

I have domain let say "example.com" with two Redhat VMs "Clinet1.example.com" and "Client2.example.com", i installed postfix server "server.example.com".
i made the configuration on both client1 and client2 to use server as relayhost.
when i send email from client1 or client2 to server it shows in the mail directory, but when i send from client1 to client2 and vice-versa it show in mail dir. in the server also and not reach the received client.
the /etc/postfix/main.cf at server as follows

```
myhostname = server.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = client1.$mydomain, client2.$mydomain, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain
mynetworks = 192.168.64.0/25, 192.168.64.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
relayhost = [server.example.com]
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
```

P.S. Firewall and selinux is off in all machines.
What is the problem?

Server log

```
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/smtpd[23972]: connect from client1.example.com[192.168.64.151]
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/smtpd[23972]: 933081037382: client=client1.example.com[192.168.64.151]
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/cleanup[23975]: 933081037382: message-id=<5eef768e.it6sAA/ACNAsXJuO%mahmod@client1.example.com>
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/qmgr[23118]: 933081037382: from=<mahmod@client1.example.com>, size=895, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/smtpd[23972]: disconnect from client1.example.com[192.168.64.151]
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/local[23976]: 933081037382: to=<root@client2.example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jun 21 17:02:38 server postfix/qmgr[23118]: 933081037382: removed
```

Cleint1 (Sender) log

```
Jun 21 17:15:37 client1 sendmail[21572]: 05LFFbl2021572: from=mahmod@client1.example.com, size=319, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<5eef7999.yBmZcYVpHOwevzri%mahmod@client1.example.com>, relay=root@localhost
Jun 21 17:15:37 client1 postfix/smtpd[21573]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 21 17:15:37 client1 postfix/smtpd[21573]: EF3A018FCB41: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 21 17:15:37 client1 postfix/cleanup[21576]: EF3A018FCB41: message-id=<5eef7999.yBmZcYVpHOwevzri%mahmod@client1.example.com>
Jun 21 17:15:38 client1 postfix/qmgr[20322]: EF3A018FCB41: from=<mahmod@client1.example.com>, size=687, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 21 17:15:38 client1 sendmail[21572]: 05LFFbl2021572: to=root@client2.example.com, ctladdr=mahmod@client1.example.com (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30319, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as EF3A018FCB41)
Jun 21 17:15:38 client1 postfix/smtpd[21573]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 21 17:15:38 client1 postfix/smtp[21577]: EF3A018FCB41: to=<root@client2.example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[192.168.64.150]:25, delay=0.2, delays=0.07/0.08/0.03/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 777BD1037382)
Jun 21 17:15:38 client1 postfix/qmgr[20322]: EF3A018FCB41: removed
```

Comment: I edited the post with log in both server and client1

Comment: These logs show the mail successfully delivered. Do you have logs of a message that was not delivered?

Comment: Yes, the mail delivered but to the server and didn't reach the client's mail directory.
it should reach mail directory at client how can i read it from the client's machine?